# Sass if has a value and else

Tags: sass

This is my mixin

```
@mixin myColor($background:null){
   @if $background == "yes"{
        background-color: white;
    }@else{
        background-color: blue;
    }
}

@include myColor; //background-color: blue;

@include myColor('yes'); //background-color: white;
```

Is there a way to make if variable `$background` is nothing `background-color: white` else `$background` is the value we give?

The function below is not working correctly, if someone could help?
Thanks!

```
  @mixin myColor($background:null){
           @if $background == $background{
                background-color: $background;
            }@else{
                background-color: blue;
            }
        }

  @include myColor(#FFFDDD); //ERROR
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. Sass allows [defaults to mixin arguments](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixin-arguments):

```
@mixin myColor($background: white){
  background-color: $background;
}

.foo {
  @include myColor
}

.bar {
  @include myColor(#00F)
}
```

Compiles to:

```css
.foo {
  background-color: white;
}

.bar {
  background-color: blue;
}
```